# JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9205: The host name supplied is not valid

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a requirement that if sending message to 1 MQ fails, then the message should be sent to 2nd MQ.
I am using IBM websphere app server `v 7.0.0.25`

Below is the relevant java code

```
methodToSendtoMQ1()
{
 try
   {
   firstQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(MANAGERFOR1);
     //send to Qmanager1
   }
   catch (MQException mqEx)
   {
      retryUsing2ndManager();
   }
}

retryUsing2ndManager()
{
   try
   {
     secondQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(MANAGERFOR2); //Code is failing here
     queue = secondQueueManager.accessQueue(someOutputQueue, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT,null,null,null);
     queue.put(responseMessage);
     queue.close();
   }
   catch (MQException mqEx)
   {
      //Here the mqEx value is populated with an exception
   }
}
```

Code is failing with below exception :

```
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'HOSTFOR1(1234)' rejected. 
[1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9205: The host name supplied is not valid. 
[3=HOSTFOR1,4=TCP]],3=HOSTFOR1(1234),5=RemoteTCPConnection.resolveHostname]
```

Below is the entry for host, channel etc.

```
HOST1=HOSTFOR1
CHANNEL1=CHANNELFOR1
MQMANAGER1=MANAGERFOR1
PORT1=1234
QNAME1=QNAMEFOR1

HOST2=HOSTFOR1
CHANNEL2=CHANNELFOR1
MQMANAGER2=MANAGERFOR2
PORT2=5678
QNAME2=QNAMEFOR1
```

Comment: *The host name supplied is not valid.* Are you sure about the validity of your Hostname & Port Number?

Comment: I don't see connection parameters being passed to MQQueueManager constructor.? Are you setting MQEnvironment somewhere else?

Comment: It looks like the connection was rejected by the server. Was the listener running? Did you see any error on the qmgr error logs?

Comment: As a slight aside, if you're using WAS as you say you are, don't use the classes for Java API as you currently are. It's bad practice. Instead, use the classes for JMS and define JMS ConnectionFactories in JNDI that can be used by the application.

Comment: And if you stick to using the Java API, use client channel definition tables to define the parameters for connecting to your different QMs, it will take care of your requirement without any Java code: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030810_.htm?lang=en